# How do I remove copy/paste touchpad controls from elementary OS Loki?

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, mouse, laptop

After installing elementary OS Loki on my laptop (Lenovo Flex 3), when I press towards the middle of the click bar on my touchpad, it will copy or paste depending on the location.  I've gone into Mouse & Touchpad settings and changing the physical click setting can disable copy and paste but also takes away my ability to "right click" with the right side of the click bar.  I want to be able to right click using my touchpad but this copy and paste has to go.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This solved my problem (although it's a bit overkill, disabling the middle click entirely). The solution above it may work as well, but haven't had time to try it. I'll write up an answer later tomorrow if I have time and no one beats me to it. https://askubuntu.com/a/55988/521915

Answer (score 1):

I also used the xmodmap solution, but this disables the middle mouse completely. 
Another solution is installing the gnome-tweak-tool from the AppCenter and disabling Middle-click Paste: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/872165/519324

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/issues/5) for this. As of elementary OS 5 and 5.1, it has been resolved and there is now a toggle in **System Settings** → **Mouse & Touchpad** → **Clicking** called **Middle click paste** that can enable or disable this behavior.